# How do you pass a while loop of PHP variables into a JS script as JSON components?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

I'm attempting to populate a JS calendar (fullCalendar plugin) with events. I have the appropriate PHP code pulling information from my database with SQL:

```
$item_results = $mysqli->query($sql_items);
$item_row = $item_results->fetch_assoc();
```

I've placed this output into a while-loop in order to rewrite all the individual results into JSON format:

```
$events = '';

while ( $item_row = $item_results->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $events .= '{title: \''. $item_row['item'] . '\', start: \'' . $item_row['expiration_date'];
    $events .= '\', color: \'' . $color . '\'' . '}, ';
  }
```

However, when I insert `'<?php echo $events; ?>'` within my JS script tag below my PHP code, it doesn't output anything to the calendar.

```
var Calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(CalendarEl, {
  events: [
   // {
   //   title: 'conference',
   //   start: '2020-02-11'
   // }
   '<?php echo $events; ?>';
 ]});
```

Is it better just to start over and split the PHP variables into arrays so I can use `json_encode()`? In this case, how would I deal with the rest of the events?

Comment: As well as never making your own JSON strings (there's really no need, you should always use json_encode, it's much easier and more reliable), you could make a better structure for your application by generating your events in a separate PHP script which can feed fullcalendar directly. See  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use array first and then use `json_encode`

```
$events = [];

while ( $item_row = $item_results->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $events[] = ["title" => $item_row['item'], "start" => $item_row['expiration_date'], "color" => $color];
  }

$events = json_encode($events,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```